# What's wrong with my php loop?

Tags: php, for-loop, foreach

I have a table called pages, and 2 entries with the same word 'about' in the column named Page. I want to create `div`s based around the number of entries with the same Page name.

This should be easy but it just can't see where it's going wrong.

I have a variable called page that i echo onto the index page it looks like this:

```
$page = pageDivs($dbc, $path['call_parts'][0])
```

The `$path` variable would equal the string 'about' in this case.

The function `pageDivs($dbc, about)` either looks like this:

```
function pageDivs($dbc, $id){
$q="SELECT * FROM pages WHERE Page='$id'";
$r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);
$data=mysqli_fetch_assoc($r);
for ($i=1; $i<count($data); $i++) {
    echo '<div id="Content'.$i.'">'.$data['Content'].'</div>';
    }
}
```

or this:

```
function pageDivs($dbc, $id){
$q="SELECT * FROM pages WHERE Page='$id'";
$r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);
$data=mysqli_fetch_assoc($r);
$i=1;
foreach ($data AS $value){
    if ($i>count($data)){
    echo '<div id="Content'.$i.'">'.$value['Content'].'</div>';
    $i++;
        }
    }
```

or this:

```
function pageDivs($dbc, $id){
$q="SELECT * FROM pages WHERE Page='$id'";
$r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);
$data=mysqli_fetch_assoc($r);
$i=1;
foreach ($data AS $key=>$value){
    if ($i>count($data)){
    echo '<div id="Content'.$i.'">'.$data[$i]['Content'].'</div>';
    $i++;
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried `fetch_assoc` and `fetch_array` and every combination except obviously the one for `$k => $v`, i've put $data everywhere or `$key` everywhere or `$value` everywhere. It's driving me nuts.

I'm obviously missing something fundamental here so someone please could you enlighten me. I really don't care if I use a `for` loop or `foreach` loop. The result should be the same. Sometimes I get 7 iterations of entry 1 others I get nothing at all. There are explicitly 2 entries with the same name so the max `div`s should be 2 in this case but I wish for it to remain dynamic.

Comment: Consult these following links http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php
and apply that to your code and var_dump and view HTML source.

Comment: (I can't be sure because it's not in the snippets) Have you opened a database connection (sorry if this is insulting)? Also, wide open to Sql Injection.

Comment: $dbc is my database connection, it's already proven to work. it's the loop that's the issue

Comment: Do you expect that the SQL SELECT statements will return multiple rows? If so, you must call `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` inside a loop to fetch all rows from it.  Calling it just once results in a 1D associative array in `$data`. Look at the `while` loop examples in the docs http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php

Answer (score 0):

While Loop was the one:

```
function pageDivs($dbc, $id){
$q="SELECT * FROM pages WHERE Page='$id'";
$r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);
$i=1;
while ($data=mysqli_fetch_assoc($r)){?> 
    <div id="Content<?php echo $i; ?>">
        <?php echo $data['Content']?>
    </div>
    <?php $i++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In `$data` variable have only one result and its better to use `mysqli_num_rows($r);` to for count purpose how many result you have.

```
<?php 
function pageDivs($dbc, $id){
$q="SELECT * FROM pages WHERE Page='$id'";
$r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);
//$data=mysqli_fetch_assoc($r);
$numofrowresult=mysqli_num_rows($r); //Count how many result you have
echo $numofrowresult;
$i = 1; //initalize counter for  the unique id

foreach($r as $values)
{
      echo '<div id="Content'.$i.'">'.$values['Content'].'</div>';
      $i++;
}
}

?>
```